# Need to make new array

Tags: php

Need Help to make new array using two array. 
One array is

```
 array:2 [▼
  "Date Date 2018-07-23" => array:1 [▼
    6 => array:2 [▼
      "avg" => 0.0
      "line_n0" => 6
    ]
  ]
  "Date Date 2018-07-28" => array:3 [▼
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "avg" => 0.031472222222222
      "line_n0" => 1
    ]
    4 => array:2 [▼
      "avg" => 0.011111111111111
      "line_n0" => 4
    ]
    5 => array:2 [▼
      "avg" => 0.011111111111111
      "line_n0" => 5
    ]
  ]
]
```

and another array is

```
        array:6 [▼
          1 => array:2 [▼
            "avg" => 0
            "line_n0" => 1
          ]
          2 => array:2 [▼
            "avg" => 0
            "line_n0" => 2
          ]
          3 => array:2 [▼
            "avg" => 0
            "line_n0" => 3
          ]
          4 => array:2 [▼
            "avg" => 0
            "line_n0" => 4
          ]
          5 => array:2 [▼
            "avg" => 0
            "line_n0" => 5
          ]
          6 => array:2 [▼
            "avg" => 0
            "line_n0" => 6
          ]



    array:2 [▼
      "Date Date 2018-07-23" => array:1 [▼
        1 => array:2 [▼
          "avg" => 0.0
          "line_n0" => 6
        ]
    2 => array:2 [▼
          "avg" => 0.0
          "line_n0" => 6
        ]
    3 => array:2 [▼
          "avg" => 0.0
          "line_n0" => 6
        ]
    4 => array:2 [▼
          "avg" => 0.0
          "line_n0" => 6
        ]
    5 => array:2 [▼
          "avg" => 0.0
          "line_n0" => 6
        ]
        6 => array:2 [▼
          "avg" => 0.0
          "line_n0" => 6
        ]
      ]
      "Date Date 2018-07-28" => array:3 [▼
        1 => array:2 [▼
          "avg" => 0.031472222222222
          "line_n0" => 1
        ]
    2 => array:2 [▼
          "avg" => 0.0
          "line_n0" => 6
        ]
    3 => array:2 [▼
          "avg" => 0.0
          "line_n0" => 6
        ]
        4 => array:2 [▼
          "avg" => 0.011111111111111
          "line_n0" => 4
        ]
        5 => array:2 [▼
          "avg" => 0.011111111111111
          "line_n0" => 5
        ]
    6 => array:2 [▼
          "avg" => 0.0
          "line_n0" => 6
        ]
      ]
    ]
```

Please help me how i will combine the array ,I want to push 2nd array element if not fund in first array key.I trying but not clear to make new array.  I have tried array merge  and array combine but not clear to make this new array.

Comment: Please edit your original post to give a **small** example of "array 1" and "array 2" and what the "merged array" would look like.

Comment: try `array_merge_recursive`.

Answer (score 0):

Use array_merge() function Example below

```
<?php
      $array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
      $array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
      $result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
      print_r($result);
?>
```

Output like this:

```
Array
(
    [color] => green
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => a
    [3] => b
    [shape] => trapezoid
    [4] => 4
)
```